# Call to a member function forceDelete() on null although dd($id) returns 19 laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to `forceDelete` an archived invoice post but it throws an error:

> Call to a member function forceDelete() on null

When I write the code at the the controller's method named `destroyarchieve()`, I write this `return $request;`.

It tells me the `id` and the `request` and here it is and I want to know why it didn't return me the `id` and it tells me only `invoice id`:

```json
{
    "_token": "NkNlrJx1y5vrsPYnrTGuoTL3iBlomJp6NOl9SOQw",
    "_method": "DELETE",
    "invoice_id": "16"
}
```

When I `dd($id)` it returns `19`. Then when I run this code:

```php
public function destroyarchieve(Request $request, $id) {
    // dd($id);
    // return $request;
    
    $i = invoices::find($id);
    $i->forceDelete();

    return back();
}
```

It throws the error.

Here is my `form` button blade page:

```html
<form action="{{ route('in.destroyarchieve', $i->id) }}" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ $i->id }}" name="invoice_id">
    <button type="submit">delete</button>
</form>
```

And my route `web.php`:

```php
Route::delete('inarchieve/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoicesController::class, 'destroyarchieve'])
    ->name('in.destroyarchieve');
```

And my controller:

```php
public function destroyarchieve(Request $request, $id) {
    // dd($id);
    // return $request;
    
    $i = invoices::find($id);
    $i->forceDelete();

    return back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't send body in delete action, remove:

```html
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $i->id }}" name="invoice_id">
```

You can send `id` only in URL and you can do like this:

```
public function destroyarchieve($id) {
    $i = invoices::findOrFail($id);
    $i->forceDelete();

    return back();
}
```

Be sure the `id` that was sent in the form action is correct:

```
{{ route('in.destroyarchieve', $i->id) }}
```

Comment: He can also take advantage of [Implicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding) so he does not need to write `$i = invoices::findOrFail($id);` as it will already do it for you.

Comment: yes , model binding is good feature , he can do that : public function destroyarchieve(Invoice $invoice) {}

in route  : Route::delete('inarchieve/{invoice}', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoicesController::class, 'destroyarchieve'])
    ->name('in.destroyarchieve');